# UserControl's Item's background

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a user control with few elements inside, one of the element I want to set it's background to Transparent, but I dont want the user of this control to be able to change it using Styles.

: for example

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForeground}" />
        </Trigger>
```

this code sets the background of the entire control (including the item I dont want to change).

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the background of the control explicitly to transparent? That should override any inherited styles.

Comment: & @HCL, I did that, but the trigger overrides this

Comment: @Pacman: May it be that you want to have your item transparent but the whole user control set to non-transparent? Something like a transparent hole in the control? This would be not possible, the way we have proposed...

Comment: @Pacman: then set the color of the control in the trigger too.